# error con msqli_num_rows

Tags: php, base-de-datos, mysqli

Soy bastante novata en el tema de la programación y estoy teniendo problemas a la hora de programar el buscador de mi web.

Esta es la página donde me dice que está el error:

```
require_once ('../bbdd/bbdd.php');

$search = '';

if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $search = $_POST['search'];
}

$consulta = "SELECT * from series where nombre LIKE '%".$search."%' ORDER BY DESC LIMIT 20";

$resultado = $conn->query($consulta);
$fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);

/*echo $fila['nombre'];*/

$total = msqli_num_rows($resultado);


if ($total >0 && $search != '') {?>
    <h2>resultados de la busqueda</h2>
 <?php do { ?>  
    <div class="nombre">
        <?php echo $fila['nombre']; ?>
    </div>
 <?php  
} while ( $fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado));  ?>  

 <?php } 

 ?>
```

cuando intento ejecutar la consulta me da dos errores:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\proyect\php\buscador.php on line 14
>
> Fatal error: Call to undefined function msqli_num_rows() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\proyect\php\buscador.php on line 18

Comment: El problema no es con mysqli_num_rows, es porque la consulta no funcionó correctamente. Asegúrate de que la conexión es correcta y de que la sentencia SQL es correcta (comparte el parámetro pasado y la sentencia generada), además podrías escribir el mensaje de error que recibes al ejecutar la sentencia SQL (con `mysqli_error`) para obtener información más detallada. Por último, nunca uses sentencias SQL dinámicas, usa sentencias preparadas; tal y como está ahora mismo el código, presenta problemas de seguridad y es vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL.

Comment: Está **mal escrito**: `$total = msqli_num_rows($resultado);`, debe ser `$total = mysqli_num_rows`. Falta la `y` después de `m`. Empieza por ahí, luego ya veremos :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya que estas utilizando la conexión como POO

prueba así

```
require_once ('../bbdd/bbdd.php');

$search = '';

if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $search = $_POST['search'];
}

$consulta = "SELECT * from series where nombre LIKE '%".$search."%' ORDER BY DESC LIMIT 20";

// comprobamos si se ejecuto correctamente
if (!$resultado = $conn->query($consulta) )
{
    // mostramos el error
    echo $conn->error;
    // finalizamos la ejecución 
    exit;
}
// cambiamos esta línea 
//$fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
$fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc();

/*echo $fila['nombre'];*/

// cambiamos esta línea tambien
//$total = msqli_num_rows($resultado);
$total = $resultado->num_rows;
```

Puedes visitar la documentación

[mysqli_result::fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

[mysqli_result::$num_rows](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)

Cómo bien te ha comentado el compañero deberías tomar medidas para protegerte contra **inyección SQL** revisa esto:

[Inyección de SQL](http://php.net/manual/es/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Comment: gracias, he hecho los cambios y ahora se que la consulta no se esta ejecutando bien. me sale $mysqli->error

Comment: muchísimas gracias!!!!!!! ya he conseguido que salgan resultados.

Answer (score 0):

Bienvenida HaileyThc!

Mira, a vista simple veo que escibiste `msqli_num_rows` la cual no existe. Existe `mysqli_num_rows`.

Y por otro lado:

```
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $search = $_POST['search'];
}
```

Entiendo que si no tiene nada `'search'` entonces no le pasara el parametro a `$search`. Sin embargo cuando se ejecute `$consulta`, esta tendra el siguiente valor:

```
$consulta = "SELECT * from series where nombre LIKE ORDER BY DESC LIMIT 20";
```

por lo que se te caera la consulta por syntaxis. Seria bueno que colocaras un else para salir de ese script para evitar llamadas a la base de datos y con devuelta de errores, esto lo haces de esta manera.

```
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $search = $_POST['search'];
}else{
    exit();
}
```

Espero que sea de utilidad y éxito en lo que estés desarrollando :D

**NOTA:**

Cuidado con ese `$consulta = "SELECT * from series where nombre LIKE '%".$search."%' ORDER BY DESC LIMIT 20";` ya que como no le estas pasando parámetros. Es fácil hacer un ataque de inyección SQL.